Does a commutative reduced ring have idempotent elements if it has zero divisors?
Suppose $A$ is a commutative reduced ring (i.e. $A$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements). If $A$ is not an integral domain, then must $A$ have nontrivial idempotent elements? If $A$ is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$, then this holds, but I'm not sure if it holds in general.

Equivalently, is every reduced connected ring (with no nontrivial nilpotents or idempotents) an integral domain?

Which means that you are looking for the difference between "connected" and "irreducible" (in geometric terms).

An Artinian reduced commutative ring must be a direct product of finitely many fields. So, no Artinian counterexample exists.

Sorry. I got the terminology wrong. Thanks again for the advice. I will give it further consideration.

$k[x,y]/(xy)$ is reduced and has no idempotents but has zero divisors.

Let $k$ be a field and consider $A=k[x,y]/(xy)$. If the image of $e \in k[x,y]$ is idempotent in $A$ then $xy\mid e(e-1)$. Suppose w.l.o.g. that $x\mid e$ and $y\mid e-1$. The first condition implies that the constant term oft $e$ equals $0$ and the second condition implies that the constant term equals $1$, a contradiction. Hence $xy\mid e$ or $xy\mid e-1$, i.e. $e=0$ or $e=1$ in $A$.
Since $xy$ is square-free, $A$ is reduced and since $xy$ is not prime, $A$ contains zero-divisors.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

@BillDubuque As far as I see, the »duplicate« is different, because nilpotent elements are allowed.

But answers (including this) are already there, even if the questions are not exactly the same.

I apologize. Due to my lack of search skills, I wasted your time. I also apologize for the delay in my response. And, Thank you for your answer. I've been thinking about it in my spare time these past few days, but I couldn't find a counterexample on my own. The example you provided was exactly what I was looking for.
